# Android Studio/kotlin how to every 60 seconds run function

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I have next a fragment code:

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    fun get_date_to_new_year(): String {
        val CurrentDate = LocalDateTime.now()
        val needDateToNewYear = LocalDateTime.of(2023, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
        val DateToNewYear = Duration.between(CurrentDate, needDateToNewYear)
        return "До нового года " + (DateToNewYear.toDays()).toString()  + " дней\nили " +
                (DateToNewYear.toHours()).toString() + " часов\nили " + (DateToNewYear.toMinutes()).toString()  + " минут\nили " +
                (DateToNewYear.seconds).toString() + " секунд"
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private var _text = MutableLiveData<String>().apply {
        value = get_date_to_new_year()
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    var text: LiveData<String> = _text
```

I need text variable to be updated every 60 seconds

Comment: I don’t have experience in Kotlin, there are probably better approaches than what I’m about to say. But you can use a scheduled thread pool, and set the execution in the pool. there are some examples on how to do that in java which you can search for, and use the same APIs in Kotlin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move this to a ViewModel, it’s pretty easy using the `liveData` coroutine builder.  No need for the MutableLiveData.

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
val text: LiveData<String> = liveData {
    while(true) {
        emit(get_date_to_new_year())
        delay(60_000)
    }
}
```

If you don’t want to use a ViewModel, you could launch a coroutine in `onViewCreated()`.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    //..
    viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
        while(true) {
            _text.value = get_date_to_new_year()
            delay(60_000)
        }
    }
}
```

But if you’re not using a ViewModel, I think the LiveData is just an unnecessary extra layer. You could update your TextView or whatever directly in the coroutine.